# Regular Expression to find all SupressMessage in solution

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression to match all references to SuppressMessage in a solution that took over.

example:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1305:SpecifyIFormatProvider", MessageId = "System.Int32.ToString")]
```

I tried this to find the SuppressMessage with the beginning and ending square brackets but it does not observe line feeds and when multiple matches are with the same file, it will return the bulk of the file.

```
\[(SuppressMessage)\((.*)\)\]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\[(SuppressMessage\((?:.*?)\))\]
```

make your expression `non greedy`.In fact try

```
\[(SuppressMessage\((?:[^)]*)\))\]
```

or

```
\[(SuppressMessage[^)]*\)))
```

to make it [**fail proof.**](https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/9)

Answer (score 0):

[(SuppressMessage)((.*?))]
try it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks vks - That got me closer but that finds two groups.

SupressMessage

"Microsoft.Design", "CA1062:Validate arguments of public methods", MessageId = "0"

What I found that works (without multiple SuppressMessages in the same square brace) is:

\[(SuppressMessage.*?)\]